# Peel n Stick Tiles For Backsplash

Tags: tile, backsplash

Looking to make a mosaic tile backsplash between my range and vent hood.  I am looking at the various tile options out there and am considering the peel and stick.  Do these really adhere as well as they state?  I am concerned with the adhesion level since I would be using them behind a range and the area is exposed to a decent amount of heat.

Comment: Never used them, but my first time wouldn't be in an area that frequently gets high heat and a steam bath in a very noticeable area.

Answer (score 1):

Never seen a peel and stick mosaic.

I use peel and stick vinyl for closet flooring in various places - cheap, easy to clean, and the expense of using a better quality flooring there does not seem to be worth it. The last batch I got was a tolerably well-done "wood-look" and had the added advantage of not stinking like the old ones (10 years or more ago) I had last used.

I would not put them in a hot/steamy/wet area - that would be best served by a more traditional mortar tile attachment, or (what my house growing up had) a sheet of stainless steel (it was easy to clean, fireproof, and somewhat predated the popularity of an "industrial look." It's not for everyone.)

Upon searching for "peel and stick mosaic" I see that the probable maker claims they are suited to the use, but I'd still take that claim with a heathy dose of salt, personally. As a confirmed pessimist I'd also take a scrap piece and try to set fire to it. Ceramic or glass is "fireproof" not merely "heat resistant." Likewise, consider the less-glowing reviews as well as the glowing ones.

Comment: My fault for not specifying but what I was considering were not the vinyl, they are ceramic with a peel and stick backer.  Basically the same but no thin set is needed - supposedly

http://www.homedepot.com/b/Smart-Tiles/N-5yc1vZ3wr

Comment: "*Smart Tiles is made of an adhesive substrate topped with a gel component called Gel-O (which gives it its 3-dimensional effect).*" Sure does not sound like "ceramic" to me. And one revewer comments that it's "about as thick as a magnet" (presumably of the sheet type.)